# Change a portion of a url

Tags: jquery

a have a url that is as follows

```
<a href="www.mysite.com/foo/content">Link</a>
```

How do I remove the "/foo" using jquery so it'll end up like this.

```
<a href="www.mysite.com/content">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('a').prop('href', function(i,href){
    return href.replace('/foo', '');
});
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'prop'

Comment: @MattCoady You're using an outdated version of jQuery, upgrade to the latest, which is 1.9 (released). Be aware, some functions are removed from 1.9, such as `.live()`. If you need these functions, simply include the jQuery migrate library, or only upgrade to jQuery 1.8